# Creating Piecewise Function Fill in the blank using Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to recreate something similar to Mark Sparks example (picture attached).  So far, I have come up with the following. However, I can't figure out how to make the big brace as well as the comma[image] as we do for piecewise functions. I am wondering if anyone can help?

Thank you for your time,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        

        \path(8,21.25)--(12,21.25)node[midway]{Equation of Each Piece};
                
                \draw[rounded corners](8,21)--(12,21)--(12,20)--(8,20)--cycle;
                
                \begin{scope}[shift={(4.25,0)}]
                    \draw[rounded corners](8,21)--(12,21)--(12,20)--(8,20)--cycle;
                    \path(8,21.75)--(12,21.75)node[midway]{Constraints of};
                    \path(8,21.25)--(12,21.25)node[midway]{Each Piece};
                \end{scope}
                
                \begin{scope}[shift={(4.25,-1.25)}]
                    \draw[rounded corners](8,21)--(12,21)--(12,20)--(8,20)--cycle;
                \end{scope}
                
                \begin{scope}[shift={(0,-1.25)}]
                    \draw[rounded corners](8,21)--(12,21)--(12,20)--(8,20)--cycle;
                \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to do it. I edited your code to use relative position and some predefined node style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations.pathreplacing}
\tikzset{
myboxl/.style={
draw,rounded corners,minimum height=1cm,minimum width=4cm,
},
myboxr/.style={
draw,rounded corners,minimum height=1cm,minimum width=2cm,
}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (fn) {$f(x)=$};
\draw [decorate,decoration=brace] ([shift={(0.2,-2)}]fn.east) -- ++(0,4);
\node (bl) [myboxl,anchor=west] at ([shift={(0.4,-1.5)}]fn.east) {};
\node (ml) [myboxl,above=0.5cm] at (bl.north) {};
\node (tl) [myboxl,above=0.5cm] at (ml.north) {};
\node (ltext) [above,text height=12pt,text depth=5pt] at (tl.north) {Equation of Each Piece};
\node (bc) [right=5pt] at ([yshift=-10pt]bl.east) {\Large\textbf{,}};
\node (mc) [right=5pt] at ([yshift=-10pt]ml.east) {\Large\textbf{,}};
\node (tc) [right=5pt] at ([yshift=-10pt]tl.east) {\Large\textbf{,}};
\node (br) [myboxr,right=0.7cm] at (bl.east) {};
\node (mr) [myboxr,right=0.7cm] at (ml.east) {};
\node (tr) [myboxr,right=0.7cm] at (tl.east) {};
\node (rtext) [above,text height=12pt,text depth=5pt,align=center] at (tr.north) {Constraint of\\Each Piece};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

> Edit: with two rows

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations.pathreplacing}
\tikzset{
myboxl/.style={
draw,rounded corners,minimum height=1cm,minimum width=4cm,
},
myboxr/.style={
draw,rounded corners,minimum height=1cm,minimum width=2cm,
}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (fn) {$f(x)=$};
\draw [decorate,decoration=brace] ([shift={(0.2,-1.2)}]fn.east) -- ++(0,2.4);
\node (bl) [myboxl,anchor=west] at ([shift={(0.4,-0.75)}]fn.east) {};
\node (tl) [myboxl,above=0.5cm] at (bl.north) {};
\node (ltext) [above,text height=12pt,text depth=5pt] at (tl.north) {Equation of Each Piece};
\node (bc) [right=5pt] at ([yshift=-10pt]bl.east) {\Large\textbf{,}};
\node (tc) [right=5pt] at ([yshift=-10pt]tl.east) {\Large\textbf{,}};
\node (br) [myboxr,right=0.7cm] at (bl.east) {};
\node (tr) [myboxr,right=0.7cm] at (tl.east) {};
\node (rtext) [above,text height=12pt,text depth=5pt,align=center] at (tr.north) {Constraint of\\Each Piece};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks amazing!! How can I adjust this to only have two rows? I tried to work with the code you gave me but I could only eliminate the comma and the right most box is the third row.

Comment: @Nick Added to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need `tikz` for this. You can use `cases` and `\framebox`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\htm}{\rule{0pt}{4mm}} % adjust 4mm to set height of boxes

\begin{document}

\[\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.6pt}
f(x)=\begin{cases}
  \framebox[4cm]{\raisebox{7mm}[0pt]{\footnotesize Equation of Each Piece}\htm}\ , 
     & \framebox[2cm]{\raisebox{8.45mm}[0pt]{\footnotesize \begin{tabular}{c}Constraint of\\[-1ex] 
     Each Piece\end{tabular}}\htm}\\[1ex]
  \framebox[4cm]{\htm}\ , & \framebox[2cm]{\htm}\\[1ex]
  \framebox[4cm]{\htm}\ , & \framebox[2cm]{\htm}
\end{cases}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you Sandy!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my proposal using a Ti*k*Z `matrix` and the `calligraphic brace` decoration from the Ti*k*Z `calligraphy` library:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing, calligraphy, matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  box/.code={%
    \ifnum\pgfmatrixcurrentrow>1
      % Draw the rectangles
      \tikzset{nodes={draw, text height=8.5pt, text depth=3.5pt}}%
    \fi
  }]

  \matrix (M) [
    matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells,
    nodes={anchor=base, align=center},
    column 1/.style={box, nodes={text width=12em}},
    column 2/.style={nodes={yshift=-0.3ex}}, % lower the commas a little bit
    column 3/.style={box, nodes={text width=6em}},
  ]
  { Equation of Each piece & &
             {\parbox[b]{6em}{\centering Constraint of\\Each Piece}}\\
     & , &\\[0.7ex]
     & , &\\[0.7ex]
     & , &\\
  };

\draw[decorate, decoration={calligraphic brace, mirror, amplitude=0.8ex},
      line width=0.6pt]
  ([xshift=-0.3em] M-2-1.north west) -- node[left] {$f(x) = {}$}
  ([xshift=-0.3em] M-4-1.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For two rows, it's almost the same (why wasn't it spelled out in the question?):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing, calligraphy, matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  box/.code={%
    \ifnum\pgfmatrixcurrentrow>1
      % Draw the rectangles
      \tikzset{nodes={draw, text height=8.5pt, text depth=3.5pt}}%
    \fi
  }]

  \matrix (M) [
    matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells,
    nodes={anchor=base, align=center},
    column 1/.style={box, nodes={text width=12em}},
    column 2/.style={nodes={yshift=-0.3ex}}, % lower the commas a little bit
    column 3/.style={box, nodes={text width=6em}},
  ]
  { Equation of Each piece & &
             {\parbox[b]{6em}{\centering Constraint of\\Each Piece}}\\
     & , &\\[0.7ex]
     & , &\\
  };

\draw[decorate, decoration={calligraphic brace, mirror, amplitude=0.8ex},
      line width=0.6pt]
  ([xshift=-0.3em] M-2-1.north west) -- node[left] {$f(x) = {}$}
  ([xshift=-0.3em] M-3-1.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]